How to make a callout after DML?
I'm making an api callout from einstein bot and waiting for the response to show in the chatbot the isssue is that the api needs a token that expires for every six hours to get resolve that I'm checking if the statuscode is 401 and I'm regenerating token and making a call but the issue is that I'm making callout after DML i'M getting the issue you've uncommited work pending How to resolve this ?
public class BotHelper {
    public static Results makeRequest(Requests chatRequest,String token,Integer recurSiveCounter){
    
    HttpRequest Request=new HttpRequest();
    Request.setEndpoint('callout:chatbot/BusBooking');
    Request.setMethod('POST');
    Request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +token);
    Request.setHeader('Accept', 'text/plain');
    Request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json-patch+json');
    
    String requestBody = '{"fromCity":"' + chatRequest.fromCity + '", "toCity":"' + chatRequest.toCity + '", "journeyDate":"' + chatRequest.journeyDate + '"}';
    Request.setBody(requestBody);
    
    System.debug(requestBody);
    
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse response = http.send(Request);
    
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        try {
            // Parse the JSON response
            BusBookingWrapper responseWrapper = (BusBookingWrapper)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),
                                                                                    BusBookingWrapper.class);
            
            // Extract the RedirectURL from the response
            if (responseWrapper.result != null &&
                responseWrapper.result.BusBookingDetails != null &&
                responseWrapper.result.BusBookingDetails.size() > 0) {
                    // Get the redirect URL from the first element and assign it to a string variable
                    String redirectUrl = responseWrapper.result.BusBookingDetails[0].RedirectURL;
                    System.debug('Redirect URL: ' + redirectUrl); 
                    Results retResult = new Results();
                    retResult.journeyUrl = redirectUrl;
                    return retResult;
                } else {
                    // Handle the case where the redirect URL is not available
                    System.debug('Redirect URL not found');
                    Results retResult = new Results();
                    retResult.journeyUrl = '';
                    return retResult;
                    
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle any exceptions during JSON deserialization or processing
            System.debug('Exception: ' + e.getMessage());
            Results retResult = new Results();
            retResult.journeyUrl = '';
            return retResult;
            
        }
    }else if(response.getStatusCode()==401){
        Chatbot_Credentials__c customChatKeys=EinsteinBotAPI.generateToken();
        if(customChatKeys!=null && customChatKeys.Token__c!=null){
            recurSiveCounter+=1;
            if(recurSiveCounter>=2){
                Results retResult = new Results();
                retResult.journeyUrl = '';
                return retResult;
            }
            return makeRequest(chatRequest,customChatKeys.Token__c,recurSiveCounter);
        }else{
            //return_empty
            Results retResult = new Results();
            retResult.journeyUrl = '';
            return retResult;
        }
    } 
    else {
        // If status code is not 200, add an empty Results object to the resultList
        Results retResult = new Results();
        retResult.journeyUrl = '';
        return retResult;
        //resultList.add(retResult);
    }
    
    //return null;   
}
@InvocableMethod(label='Get Bus Booking URL' description='This method returns a bus booking URL')
public static List<Results> getBusbookingURL(List<Requests> chatbotRequests) {
    List<Results> resultList=new List<Results>();
    List<Chatbot_Credentials__c> clientCredentials=[Select Id,ApiKey__c,Token__c,Expiration_Date__c
                                                    from Chatbot_Credentials__c
                                                    where Name='Chatbot_Keys' limit 1];
    Chatbot_Credentials__c customChatKeys;
    if(!clientCredentials.isEmpty()){
        customChatKeys=clientCredentials[0]; 
        if(Datetime.now()>=customChatKeys.Expiration_Date__c){
            customChatKeys=EinsteinBotAPI.generateToken();
        }
    }else{
        customChatKeys=EinsteinBotAPI.generateToken();
    }
    
    for(Requests req:chatbotRequests){
        Results res=makeRequest(req,customChatKeys.Token__c,0);
        resultList.add(res);
    }
    
    
    return resultList;   
}

public class Requests {
    @InvocableVariable(label='fromCity' description='From City' required=true)
    public String fromCity;
    @InvocableVariable(label='toCity' description='To City' required=true)
    public String toCity;
    @InvocableVariable(label='JourneyDate' description='JourneyDate' required=true)
    public String journeyDate;
}

public class Results {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Constructed URL' description='Constructed URL' required=true)
    public String journeyUrl;
}

}

I am guessing EinsteinBotAPI.generateToken is performing DML to store the new token. You need to avoid this, storing the token only after the callout is done.

Hey thanks for the suggestion @phil W I've changed the code to get new token using api and using that token to make a request and updating the code using future method in another transaction

Hi @PhilW The issue still exists , I'm making an DML after callout in future method but it's still saying "You have uncommitted work pending"

You need to figure out what that is; best way is to enable debug and look for where DML (database insert, update, delete) happens in the transaction before the callout is made.

I figured it out @PhilW the issue is when token is expired it's giving me a 401 status code and what I'm doing is getting new token and updating the token in future method and retrying the callout how can I mitigate the issue

Get the new token, use it to do the callout then store the token after the callout completes.

Yes, @PhilW I fired an platform event "publish immediately" to update the token in org
